# "pois não" has an affirmative connotation whereas "pois sim" has a negative one. How come?

Tags: etimologia, diferenças-transatlânticas

How did the Portuguese Language come to coin such apparently nonsensical phrases?  In Brazilian Portuguese **"pois não"** is a very polite way of saying **"yes"** both as a statement and as a question.

- Shop assistent to client - **Pois não?**  (Can I help you?)
- Client to shop assistent - Posso experimentar aquele perfume? (Can I try that fragrance?)
- Shop assistant to client - **Pois não!** (meaning "yes", as an answer)

Then again, "pois sim" means exactly the opposite.

- "Susan disse que você não é páreo pra ela no tênis"
- **"Pois sim!!!** Deixa estar.

"Susan says you are no match for her at tennis"
"Pois sim!!!" would be something like "of course not. Let her wait and see")

The question is: When did these idioms begin to be used?  Did they mean the same  then, as they do now?

**This question refers to the use of "pois não" and "pois sim" in ptBR**. Any information about the use of these phrases in ptPT will be welcome, though.

Comment: The idea is that it basically is like [question tags](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question#In_English)

Comment: Related, though perhaps more instantly understandable, consider how Spanish has _¡cómo no!_ meaning ‘of course’ (= ‘how [could it] not [be so]?’).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(In English below.)

**Pois sim** é usado em Portugal exatamente como no exemplo da pergunta:

> "Susan disse que você não é páreo pra ela no tênis"
>
> “Pois sim!!! Deixa estar.”

**Pois sim** aqui é claramente irónico. Ironia é precisamente uma forma de dar a entender o contrário do significado literal das palavras usadas: embora literalmente **pois sim** signifique sim, qualquer falante nativo entende que o locutor está a exprimir ceticismo ou desacordo relativamente ao que foi dito antes. Outra formas irónicas usadas em Portugal (e no Brasil?) para exprimir o mesmo sentimento são **sim, sim! "pois, pois!** e **está bem, está!**

Para determinar se palavras são usadas literal ou ironicamente, na fala, locutor e ouvinte socorrem-se do contexto e entoação. Com entoação e contexto certos, **sim, sim** ou **pois, pois** podem de facto querer dizer sim. Na escrita, sem o benefício da entoação, poderemos ter que recorrer a frases adicionais como o *deixa estar* do exemplo da pergunta, ou “ ‘Pois sim,’ disse ela ironicamente.”

Não sendo a ironia um exclusivo dos lusófonos, provavelmente existem construções semelhantes noutras línguas. Existe pelo menos no Inglês: “yeah, yeah!”

**Pois não** não é usado em Portugal para implicar sim, mas é reconhecido devido à exposição a televisão brasileira. Além do mais, por trás do disparate aparente há um sentido perfeitamente lógico. No diálogo:

> Cliente: "Posso experimentar aquele perfume?"
>
> Empregado: "Pois não!"

o **pois não** é, estou convencido, um vestígio da pergunta retórica:

> Pois não haveria de poder?!

Um programa de computador pouco sofisticado entenderia a pergunta **pois não haveria de poder?** como uma especulação sobre se o cliente deveria ou não ser autorizado a experimentar o perfume, mas qualquer falante nativo entende essa pergunta como retórica e querendo significar **claro que pode.**

Usa-se em Portugal um construção semelhante, **então não?!** com o mesmo significado que **pois não!** mas implicando alguma familiaridade entre locutor e ouvinte e, por isso, pouco apropriado em situações formais. Poderia ser usado, por exemplo, entre colegas de trabalho:

> "Vamos almoçar. Queres vir?" diz a Joana. "Então não?!" responde o Fábio.

Também aqui, o **então não!** é quase de certeza uma contração da pergunta retórica

> Então não haveria de querer?!

Do mesmo modo:

> "Ajuda-me a levar estes sacos lá para cima?" "Então não haveria de ajudar?!"

Eu iria jurar que já ouvi ou li perguntas retóricas como as anteriores com **pois** em vez de **então**, e entendo-as exatamente da mesma maneira. Afinal, nessas frases, **então** e **pois** são pouco (ou nada?) mais que interjeições. Novamente, contexto e entoação são fundamentais para determinar o sentido de **pois não**. Creio todos os falantes nativos de português identificarão imediatamente o significado do **pois não** nos exemplos seguintes:

> “João, ela disse que tu não a convidaste para a tua festa de aniversário,” disse o Pedro. “Pois não!” respondeu o João perentoriamente, “ela também não me convidou para a festa dela.”
>
> “Ela no fundo não é egoísta,” continuou o Pedro. “Pois não! Que ideia?! Nadinha mesmo!” responde o João.

**ENGLISH**

**”Pois sim”** is used in Portugal exactly as in the example in the question:

> “Susan disse que você não é páreo pra ela no tênis.” “Pois sim!!! Deixa estar.” (“Susan said you are no match for her at tennis.” “Pois sim!!! Let her talk.”)

**“Pois sim”** is here clearly ironical. Irony is precisely a way of meaning the opposite of the literal meaning of the words used: even though “**pois sim**” literally means “yes”, any native speaker will understand that the speaker is expressing scepticism or disagreement regarding what has just been said. Other ironical ways used in Portugal (and in Brasil?) to express the same feeling are “**sim, sim!**” and “**pois, pois!**” and “**está bem, está!**”

Speaker and listener use context and intonation in speech to determine whether words are being used ironically or literally. With the right intonation and context, “**sim, sim!**” and “**pois, pois!**” can actually mean “yes.” In writing, without the benefit of intonation, we can resort to additional phrases like the “deixa estar” of the example (literally, “let it be,” possibly better translated as “let her talk”), or “ ‘Pois sim,’ she said ironically.”

Irony is not the exclusive preserve of Portuguese speakers, so similar constructions probably exist in other languages. English has the “yeah, yeah!”

“**Pois não**” is not used in Portugal to imply “yes,” but will be understood as such owing to exposure to Brazilian TV. Besides, under the seemingly nonsensical “pois não” lies very sound logic. In the example

> Customer: “Posso experimentar aquele perfume? (“May I try that perfume?”)
>
> Shop assistant: “Pois não!”

the “**pois não**” is, I firmly believe, a vestige of a rhetorical question:

> “Pois não haveria de poder?!” (“Wouldn´t you be allowed to?!”)

An unsophisticated computer would interpret the question “Pois não haveria de poder?!” as someone speculating whether the customer should be allowed to try the perfume, but any native speaker will understand it as a rhetorical question meaning “**of course you can.**”

A similar construction, “**então não?!**” is used with the same meaning in Portugal, but implying some familiarity between speakers and, therefore, not very appropriate in formal settings. It could be used, for instance, among work mates:

> “Vamos almoçar. Queres vir?” (“We’re going for lunch. Want to come?”)
>
> “Então não?!”

Here too, the “**então não?!**” is most certainly a contraction of the rhetorical question:

> “Então não haveria de querer?!” (“(Would I not want to?!”)

Similarly

> “Ajuda-me a levar estes sacos lá para cima?” (“Will you help me carry these bags upstairs?”)
>
> “Então não haveria de ajudar?!” (“Would I not help you?!”)

I would swear that I have heard or read such rhetorical questions with a “**pois não**” substituted for “**então não**”, and I understand them as exactly the same. After all, in those sentences, “**então**” and “**pois**” are little, if anything, more than interjections. Again, context and intonation are key in determining the exact meaning of “**pois não.**” I believe any native Portuguese speakers will immediately identify the meaning of “**pois não**” in the following examples:

> “João, ela disse que tu não a convidaste para a tua festa de aniversário,” disse o Pedro. “Pois não!” respondeu o João perentoriamente, “ela também não me convidou para a festa dela.” (“João, she said you did not invite her for your birthday party,” Pedro said. “Pois não!” João peremptorily replied, “she didn’t invite me for hers either.”)
>
> “Ela no fundo não é egoísta,” continuou o Pedro. “Pois não! Que ideia?! Nadinha mesmo!” responde o João. (“She is nor really selfish,” Pedro went on. “Pois não! The very idea! Not the slightest little bit!” João replied.)

Comment: Since the question was asked in English, are you considering a translation of this answer?

Comment: Very good explanation.   O "então não!", responde o Fábio, não seria com ponto de interrogação (?).  Acho que pouco se ouve "então não" no Brasil, mas se vier com a intonação de uma pergunta (então não?) eu entenderia.

Comment: Há possivelmente um simetria entre o _pois não_ no Brasil e o _então não_ em Portugal (à parte da informalidade do _então não_) Tal como já não é necessário o ponto de interrogação no _pois não_ no Brasil (mas facilitaria em Portugal se não o conhecêssemos das novelas) também não já não é necessário no _então não_ em Portugal. É uma daquelas entoações entre a pergunta e a exclamação.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I just want to emphasize that "pois não" has basically an affirmative meaning in Brazil, i.e. yes! (sure!) or yes? (can I help you?) And, to me, "pois sim" is ironical 99% of the time. A different intonation might possibly convey a non-ironical use to me.

Comment: @Centaurus Do brazilians also say "sim, sim!", "pois, pois!, or "está bem, está!" to ironically to mean "I doubt it", "rubish"?

Comment: "Tá bem!!!" is commonly heard. Giving it the right intonation it means "I doubt it" as you said.  We never use "pois, pois" or "ora pois".  Sim, sim.. might mean "I doubt it" but requires ironical intonation and speaking somewhat slowly: siimm.

Comment: @Centaurus Afinal este *pois não* já se usou em Portugal. É coisa antiga. Encontrei-o n'[*A Rosa do Adro* (1870) de Manoel M. Rodrigues](https://www.luso-livros.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/A-Rosa-do-Adro.pdf): "A mamã dá licença, não é verdade? — Pois não, minha filha! A pergunta era escusada." E ouve-se algumas vezes no filme [O Leão da Estrela (1947)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO563Q-DUYI).

Answer (score 8):

Your question seems to derive from a few misconceptions about the meaning of *"pois não"* and *"pois sim"* in those particular contexts.

Firstly, *"pois não?"* is a typical Brazilian means of formally saying "can I help you?", and "pois não" as a positive reply is actually an intensifier of the idea, rather than a negator. In both cases, the aim of the adverb *"não"* is to exhibit surprise upon the asker for wondering that the answer could be negative [[1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pois-simpois-nao/3221)] (thanks, @ANeves).

As for the other one, *"pois sim"* can hold a negative meaning as much as *"com certeza"*, *"claro"* and *"está bem"*, just as long as it's part of an ironic (possibly sarcastic) statement. These expressions can fill in the following blank:

> - Hoje corri 10 quilómetros.
> - ________. Vou acreditar nisso.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note that I'm from Portugal, but I think it's the same way in Brazil</sup>

This *does* make sense! It's comparable to [question tags, in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question#In_English) :

*You speak English, **don't you**?*.

The above sentence would be translated as *Falas inglês, não é?*, where *não é* has the same value as (but can't be replaced by) *pois sim*. However, the sentence

*You **don't** speak English, **do you**?*

Would translate as:

*Não falas inglês, **pois não**?*

As [@ANeves points out](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/pois-n%C3%A3o-has-an-affirmative-connotation-whereas-pois-sim-has-a-negative-one/1018?noredirect=1#comment2545_1018), *pois sim*, is used to denote irony; they also say it could be used as a synonym of *pois não*, with which I disagree. I *have* heard people saying this, but it *does not sound natural* to me (just me?).

Also, approaching a costumer and saying "*Pois não?* " *is* nonsensical, in Portugal, but [@bfavaretto confirms it's fine in Brazil](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/pois-n%C3%A3o-has-an-affirmative-connotation-whereas-pois-sim-has-a-negative-one/1018?noredirect=1#comment2541_1018).

Comment: "Note that I'm from Portugal, but I think it's the same way in Brazil"

Comment: @BrunoLopes as a Portuguese person, I confirm that saying "Pois não?" is extremely unusual.

Comment: Well, in Brazil it's not nonsensical to say this to a costumer. It's not so common though, but if a costumer is approached with "Pois não" it's totally fine. It's just a bit formal.

Comment: I'm just saying based on life experience. If I'm wrong, so some other Brazilian please tell me.

Comment: I confirm what @BrunoLopes said, *pois não* can mean "can I help you" in Brazil.

Comment: This answer still doesn't explain the _pois sim_ case.

Comment: I absolutely disagree that it's the same case. For me, `pois sim` is either [synonim with "pois não"](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pois-simpois-nao/3221), or the opposite but due to **irony**.

Comment: @someonewithpc Pretty sure it ain't. See my answer.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the Portuguese use "pois" much more frequently than Brazilians.  "pois sim", "ora pois", "ora, pois pois", "pois é", "pois é que é...", etc.  "Pois não?" as a question, in ptBR means exactly "Can I help you?"   If you address some bank clark, policeman, a receptionist, etc, if they want to sound polite, they will immediately ask you:  "pois não?"   or may be just an interrogative "sim?"  In the affirmative form, as an answer to a request, "pois não" means yes, certainly,

Comment: @ANeves Yeah, you're right

Comment: As for "pois sim" it will be sarcastic in 99% of the times you hear it in Brazil and means "of course not". e;g;  "pois sim, ele que se atreva !!!"

Comment: @ANeves [Ciberdúvidas out of Lisboa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pois-simpois-nao/3221) seems to confirm that *pois sim* means the same as *pois não* in Portugal (and that both mean *sim, claro*), as you have yourself said. Irony and intonation are important clues here, although some sources suggest a possible origin in a contraction/apocopation of the longer expression *pois não havia de*.

Comment: @tchrist Context and intonation are key, but in Portugal anyway _pois sim_ to mean _yes_ is rather old fashioned, and I'm not even aware of _pois não_ as _yes_; I've always understood it as a (perfectly comprehensible) Brazilianism. I am not sure Ciberdúvidas is explaining the phrases as used in Portugal only.

Comment: +1 por em causa o uso do *pois não* em Portugal.

Comment: Is it not possible to echo the verb when using question tags? I heard that it is possible. For example; "Não falas inglês, não falas?"... Or is this not ususally done?

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do que foi dito, nalgumas comunidades rurais do Norte ainda se usa 'pois não'. Mas é em geral considerado um arcaísmo que sobreviveu intacto no Brasil.

Já agora, se querem arcaísmos do português, vejam os crioulos de Cabo Verde, e possivelmente de outros locais (Guiné, Índia, Malaca...). Cheiinhos deles...